# What is coffee effect on muscles ? On sport performances?

Tags: muscles

Since coffee is a vaso-restrictor does it have any impact on sport performances ?

I mean does it go against natural way the body works (sending more blood to muscles due to the increasing needs) or does the body easily bypass this effect ?

Edit : I leanred that coffee has a great impact on sport performances but what realy interests me is to learn more about its vaso-restrictive effect , how doesn't it reduces performances ?

Comment: Did you do any research on the subject prior to posing the question here?  To my understanding, If information is easily accessible by a google-search, the moderators and other users here will ask you to do research in advance and possible rephrase the question to be more specific.

Comment: I learned that coffee increases performances but i don't find a lot to learn on it's vaso-restrictor effects which is what realy interests me

Comment: I would advise you to then clarify in your question that you have done prior research and now search for answers regarding a specific area. I am no expert on the subject you are asking about, so I apologize if my comments seem unnecessary. I am merely trying to improve your chances for finding a useful answer.

Comment: Ty for this comment , i'll edit the question ! :)